# Space between menu and drop down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, html-lists, navbar

I'd like for the drop down menu to show below the border line in the main menu area instead of showing up right underneath the 'menu' title/button. I can change the positioning so that it is lower but then there is dead space in between that makes it impossible to mouse over the drop down menu.

I don't want to add padding above the drop down because that just created more purple space, where I want that space to be empty.

Below is the code but feel free to view here:
[link](http://questionsdefemmesrevue.com/newTemplate/)

html:

```
<div class="menu-box fl">

<ul class="menu">

  <!-- Begin Item With Drop -->
  <li class="drop">
    <a href="#"><span class="big-text">menu</span></a>

    <!-- Begin Toggle Icon -->
    <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    <!-- End Toggle Icon -->

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">CSS & XHTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dreamweaver</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- End Item With Drop -->

</ul>


</div><!--end menu-->
<div class="social fl">
</div><!-- end social-->
<div class="email fr">
</div><!--end email-->

<div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--end nav-inner-->

</div><!--end nav-->
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
height: 65px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #999;  
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.nav-inner {
width:1000px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:65px;    
}

.menu-box {
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #999;
}
ul.menu {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:20px 0 0 6px;
position:relative;
float: right;
}
ul.menu li {
display:block;
height: 30px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:0 9px 0 0;
padding:0;
width:140px;
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
-khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
-moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
opacity: 0.75;           /* fx, safari, opera */

}
li.drop a {
color:#333;
line-height:30px;
}
ul.menu li ul li a {
color:#ffffff;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
width:140px;
color:#fffff;

}

.big-text {
font-size:1.5em;
}
ul.menu li.drop span.toggle {
display:block;
float:left;
width:31px;
height:30px;
background:transparent url("images/toggle1.png") no-repeat 0 -30px;
padding:0;
margin:0 7px 0 0;
color:#ffffff;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul.menu li.drop:hover span.toggle, ul.menu li.drop.current span.toggle {
background-position:0px 0px;
}

ul.menu li.drop:hover ul {-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
display:block;
z-index:1;
position: absolute;

z-index:100;
}
ul.menu li ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
top:30px;
left:0;
list-style-type:none;
padding-top:10px;
background:#461b47;
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */

}

ul.menu li ul li {
float: none;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
color: #ffffff;
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: none;
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.menu li ul li a {
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
}

.social {
width:300px;
height:100%;
}
.email {
width:500px;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Pleas don't link to live sites. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these two things in your css:

```
ul.menu li {
  display:block;
  height: 50px; /* CHANGED THIS FROM 30px TO 50px */
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 9px 0 0;
  padding:0;
  width:140px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
  opacity: 0.75;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}

ul.menu li ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:30px;
  margin-top: 18px; /* ADDED THIS VALUE */
  left:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-top:10px;
  background:#461b47;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */ 
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrFK5/1/)

I think that should achieve what you need without interfering with the layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can position your ul:hover absolutely and add top:60px; to it's styling

```
ul.menu li.drop:hover ul {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
padding-bottom: 8px;
top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that I can't get to the drop down menu, once I move my mouse from the main menu button the drop down will dissapear