# Gap Between dropdown menu and sub menu

Tags: html, css

I'd like for the menu sub menu to show 10 pixels underneath the menu, i can achieve that using margin-top on the ul, but then i cant move my mouse down to the sub menu because there is a gap. There are posts very similar to this but i could't extract an answer from them. Like this one

[Space between menu and drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820108/space-between-menu-and-drop-down-menu)

```css
deepMenu {
  background: black !important;
  margin-left: 100px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}
.lmao li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
.lmao li ul li {
  display: none;
  border-top: 0.1px solid #F2F2F2;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: white;
  font-size: 8pt;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}
.lmao li:hover > ul,
.lmao li:hover > ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lmao">
  <li class="point1"><a href="index.html">home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 long lel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3 really bare long mad</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4 dvg</a></li>
    </ul>

    <li class="point"><a href="index.html">features</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a></li>
      </ul>

      <li class="point layout"><a href="#">Layouts</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sfdgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgdfgsdgsdf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sfdgsdfgsdfgl</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">dfsgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a></li>
          <li class="arrow"><a href="#">sfgsdfg</a>
            <ul class="deepMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="point"><a href="index.html">pages</a></li>
      <li class="point"><a href="index.html">light version</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't try `.lmao li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
border-top: 5px solid black;
margin-top: 0px;
}` [check this demo](http://jsbin.com/tigiviluti/edit?html,output)

Comment: It's better using padding not margins in this case. try to change it in your class menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Now that you gave the reference, the hover menu is not actually distant from the li itself, but it is positioned right below it. On the example site the li has a height bigger than the text within and has position: relative; on it.

The dropdown is absolute positioned right below this bigger `<li>` element with a `top: 100%;` that way it is distant from the text that triggers the dropdown.

Check the updated Snippet bellow with an updated solution.

---

Margins are not 'hoverable', and therefore the hover selector is not triggered. One way to keep it distant whilst 'hoverable' is to use `padding` instead of margins.

So you could change your `.lmao li ul`, although I wouldn't advise adding style to tags as a CSS best practice, I usually adopt a CSS naming convention such as BEM, SMACSS, among others.

```css
/* Reset the ul style */
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

deepMenu {
  background: black !important;
  margin-left: 100px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.lmao {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.lmao li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.lmao li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.lmao li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f38763;
}

.lmao li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.lmao li ul li {
  display: none;
  border-top: 0.1px solid #F2F2F2;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: white;
  font-size: 8pt;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}
.lmao li:hover > ul,
.lmao li:hover > ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lmao">
  <li class="point1"><a href="index.html">home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 long lel</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3 really bare long mad</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4 dvg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <li class="point"><a href="index.html">features</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfg</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <li class="point layout"><a href="#">Layouts</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sfdgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgdfgsdgsdf</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sfdgsdfgsdfgl</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">dfsgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</a>
          </li>
          <li class="arrow"><a href="#">sfgsdfg</a>
            <ul class="deepMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="point"><a href="index.html">pages</a>
      </li>
      <li class="point"><a href="index.html">light version</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Padding on what though?

Comment: i have tired padding-top on the lmao li ul and padding-bottom on the ul.lmao and it doesnt work.

Comment: @RhysEdwards I've updated the answer to reflect what I meant.

Comment: @RhysEdwards Has the updated question helped you solving your problem? If you have any further questions fell free to ask.

Comment: Hi, that's helped a bit and i will certainly look into better naming conventions. But by adding padding its created a gap between the the top of my drop down and its border top. See i want the ul on the dropdown to have a border top like on this website:

Comment: Try hover over the nav options... http://demo.themeruby.com/maple/?home_layout=classic&light_style=1#038;light_style=1/page/2/

Comment: @RhysEdwards Hi! I got it now, I've done another update to the question to tackle that specific problem. Thanks for the reference it was helpful to figure out what was the intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background-color: #cac3bc
}
nav {
 float: left;
}
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
}
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
 }
 nav ul {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 0 20px;  
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 margin-right: -80px;
}
 nav ul li {
 float: left;
}
  nav ul li:hover {
   border-bottom: 5px solid #f5aa65;
            color: #fff;
   
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
   color: #000;
  }
 
 nav ul li a {
  display: block; 
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #000; 
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 nav ul ul {
 background-color:#fff;
 border-radius: 0px; 
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
 nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
 }
  nav ul ul li a {
   padding: 15px 40px;
   color: #000;
  }

nav ul ul:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">One</a>
         <ul>
    <li><a href="1.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.html">B</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="3.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="5.html">C</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="6.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="7.html">B</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="8.html">Four</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```